# Trying to compile HSL to get IPOPT

Tags: ipopt

Got the academic .tar for HSL but I'm still new to doing manual builds so I messed it up somewhere trying to follow the documentation here: https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node14.html.

File structure is as follows:

```
CoinIpopt
|
|---build\
|---buildtools\
|---ThirdParty\
|    |
|    |-Blas
|    |-ASL
|    |-Lapack
|    |-HSL
|       |-coinhsl-2014.01.10
|          |-ma28\
|             |-ma28d.f
|          |-ma27\
|       |-tar.tar
|       |-configure.exe
|-Ipopt
|  |-examples\
|  |-src\
|  |-configure.exe
```

When I run `./configure` from `../HSL` or `../HSL/coinhsl-2014.01.10` everything runs without error but when I try to `./configure` from `CoinIpopt/Ipopt` I get an error that it can't find any associated solvers in the HSL file:

```
checking whether va_copy is declared... yes
checking whether -lblas has BLAS... yes
checking whether LAPACK is already available with BLAS library... yes
configure: Checking for Harwell subroutine library
checking for ./../ThirdParty/HSL/ma27ad.f... no
checking for ./../ThirdParty/HSL/mc19ad.f... no
checking for ./../ThirdParty/HSL/ma57ad.f... no
configure: error: "No linear solver (such as MA27) available.  You need to provide at least one."
```

I could move the second layer of the HSL file to be inplace of the first but even so the files are different (ma27d.f vs ma27ad.f).

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved] Apparently manually renaming the files is required. https://projects.coin-or.org/svn/BuildTools/ThirdParty/HSL/stable/1.3/INSTALL.HSL

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to make it to work.

```
git clone https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL.git
cd ThirdParty-HSL
```

Download the HSL from their [website](https://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/ipopt/). Move the directory coinhsl-x.y.z to coinhsl and copy inside `ThirdParty-HSL` directory

```
mv coinhsl coinhsl-x.y.z
```

Then go back to the `ThirdParty-HSL` directory

```
cd ..
```

Then:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now you should have the HSL problem sorted for IPOPT.