# Set env variable for HSL so IPOPT can use the solver `ma57`

Tags: linux, ipopt

I am sorry but I am not good at setting environment variables / manual builds. I have downloaded the HSL solvers for IPOPT and I believe that I successfully install the whole package but I cannot set the environment variables so I can use it from IPOPT. I am getting this error message:

```
Exception message: Selected linear solver MA57 not available.
Tried to obtain MA57 from shared library "libhsl.so", but the following error occured:
libhsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I went according this advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655434/12312879 but I am not sure what to do next. The last command `sudo make install` printed this:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1 /usr/local/lib/libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1 libcoinhsl.so.2 || { rm -f libcoinhsl.so.2 && ln -s libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1 libcoinhsl.so.2; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1 libcoinhsl.so || { rm -f libcoinhsl.so && ln -s libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1 libcoinhsl.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcoinhsl.lai /usr/local/lib/libcoinhsl.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a current (3.14) Ipopt, then try setting Ipopt option [hsllib](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html#OPT_hsllib) to `/usr/local/lib/libcoinhsl.so`.
If Ipopt is older, then it doesn't have the `hsllib` option. You can try copying your `libcoinhsl.so.2.2.1` to `libhsl.so` and ensure that Ipopt finds it (e.g., by having its path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

I you build Ipopt from source, then the preferred way would be to provide HSL at buildtime, see also https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html#DOWNLOAD_HSL.